# How to cut the content of a string till a particular string or position?

Tags: c++, linux

After all my research, I am here to cut this string :

```
{[(2015/11/30|01:07:53.357|-1227639088|DefaultThread|./src/Myprogram.cpp:564|int main(int, argv**))]} Server Starting....
```

to string:

```
./src/Myprogram.cpp:564|int main(int, argv**))]} Server Starting....
```

Below is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

    void func(std::ostream&obj){
        std::string dbgmsg =  dynamic_cast<std::ostringstream&>(obj).str();
        cout << dbgmsg; //I need to convert this string to ./src/Myprogram.cpp:564|int main(int, argv**))]} Server Starting....
    }

    int main() {

        std::ostringstream ss;
        ss <<"{[(2015/11/30|01:07:53.357|-1227639088|DefaultThread|./src/Myprogram.cpp:564|int main(int, argv**))]} Server Starting....";
        func(ss);

        return 0;
    }
```

My GCC: gcc version 4.5.3 (GCC)

Comment: Have you tried using string::substring? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/

Answer (score 0):

At last I found the solution :) here is it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

void func(std::ostream&obj){
    std::string dbgmsg =  dynamic_cast<std::ostringstream&>(obj).str();     
    std::size_t pos = dbgmsg.find("./");
    std::string str3 = dbgmsg.substr (pos);
    cout << str3; //now o/p :  ./src/Myprogram.cpp:564|int main(int, argv**))]} Server Starting....
}

int main() {

    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss <<"{[(2015/11/30|01:07:53.357|-1227639088|DefaultThread||./src/Myprogram.cpp:564|int main(int, argv**))]} Server Starting....";
    func(ss);

    return 0;
```

}

Comment: You can remove the line std::string str2 = dbgmsg.substr (12,12); since you are not using it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` to find the 4th occurence of `|` and then `substring`

```
void func(std::ostream&obj){
    std::string dbgmsg =  dynamic_cast<std::ostringstream&>(obj).str();
    int occurrences = 0;
    int start = 0;

    while (occurrences !=4 && (start = dbgmsg.find("|", start)) != string::npos) {
        ++occurrences;
        ++start; 
    }

    if (start != string::npos)
    {
        cout << dbgmsg.substr (start);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jerome for your answer, I too found a solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but here's my solution

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string getString(std::string fullString){
    int pos = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        pos = fullString.find("|", pos+1);
    }
    return fullString.substr(pos+1);
}
int main( void ){
    std::string str("{[(2015/11/30|01:07:53.357|-1227639088|DefaultThread|./src/Myprogram.cpp:564|int main(int, argv**))]} Server Starting....");
    std::cout << getString(str) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```