# Printing out std::string crashes with segmentation fault error

Tags: c++, stdstring

I was trying to improve my reply to another question here [How to cut the content of a string till a particular string or position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29196061/how-to-cut-the-content-of-a-string-till-a-particular-string-or-position/29196392#29196392) to use pointer arithmetic and `std::substr` so I ended up with the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

std::string getString(std::string fullString){
    char string[80];
    char* endString;
    strcpy(string, fullString.c_str());
    strtok(string, "|");
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        endString = strtok(NULL, "|");
    }
    return fullString.substr(endString - string, std::string::npos);
}
int main( void ){
    std::string str("{[(2015/11/30|01:07:53.357|-1227639088|DefaultThread|./src/Myprogram.cpp:564|int main(int, argv**))]} Server Starting....");
    std::cout << getString(str) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However that crashes with a segmentation fault error,  if I change it to

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

std::string getString(std::string fullString){
    char string[80];
    char* endString;
    strcpy(string, fullString.c_str());
    strtok(string, "|");
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        endString = strtok(NULL, "|");
    }
    std::cout << fullString.substr(endString - string, std::string::npos) << std::endl;
    return fullString.substr(endString - string, std::string::npos);
}
int main( void ){
    std::string str("{[(2015/11/30|01:07:53.357|-1227639088|DefaultThread|./src/Myprogram.cpp:564|int main(int, argv**))]} Server Starting....");
    std::cout << getString(str) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The program runs fine and the output is as expected

```
./src/Myprogram.cpp:564|int main(int, argv**))]} Server Starting....
./src/Myprogram.cpp:564|int main(int, argv**))]} Server Starting....
```

why does it crash on the first scenario?

Comment: Are you going to make me manually diff your code? -.- Can't you narrow this down some?

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was short enough to skim through it easily, my bad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your input string is 120 bytes wide. Your C-string buffer is 80 bytes wide. Hrmm.

**Use the *find* functions instead of this error-prone C nonsense!!**

To get everything since the last `|`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

std::string getString(const std::string& fullString)
{
    size_t pos = fullString.rfind('|');
    if (pos == std::string::npos)
       throw std::runtime_error("Could not find a '|'!");

    return fullString.substr(pos+1);
}

int main()
{
    std::string str("{[(2015/11/30|01:07:53.357|-1227639088|DefaultThread|./src/Myprogram.cpp:564|int main(int, argv**))]} Server Starting....");
    std::cout << getString(str) << std::endl;
}
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7da62ff3ae961565))

Adjust as needed to scan back for the 2nd, 3rd, 4th `|`.

Comment: Ah, being idiotic and putting up an arbitrary value for buffer size, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your program has undefined behaviour because the length of the string stored in `str` is greater than 80 characters. Thus in this statement

```
strcpy(string, fullString.c_str());
```

you overwrite memory beyond array string.

Moverover it is a bad approach to use C function `strtok` instead of member function `find` (or `rfind`) of class `std::string`.

Also it is not clear why exactly magic number 4 is used in the loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    endString = strtok(NULL, "|");
}
```